# Social Login issue

Tags: plugin-duktoauth

Hope all is good. One of our clients wants to migrate project from core PHP to Craft CMS. I'm still new to Craft. My major task is to integrate custom social oAuth provider in CMS project, but before that I was trying to use built-in implementations (Google & Facebook). I setup test applications on Google and FB and I also included a social login plugin too in project ref: https://dukt.net/craft/social. I was successfully redirected from my app to google login and then permission page, but when redirected to my profile page I am getting cURL Error **(cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate**

I googled a lot, but couldn't find a proper solution.

Please find the attached screenshot
[image: Getting error after authentication]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really Craft related, but that cURL error is because you're trying to connect to an https endpoint, but your local server doesn't have a matching certificate to verify against.

You can see here for some solutions across different environments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate